# Need help on explaning javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, hash

I just found this code snippet that has to do with filtering hash tag but I don't understand what is it trying to do, and I'm not sure what to google either.

Thanks for the heads up...

```
var index = 0;
var hash = window.location.hash; //store the entered hash value eg, #02

if (hash) {
    index = /\d+/.exec(hash)[0];
    index = (parseInt(index) || 1) - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `if (hash) {`: If `hash` is **not** a garbage value like `undefined`, `null` or empty string.
- `index = /\d+/.exec(hash)[0]`: Look for the first number inside the hash, for example inside `#432` that would be `432` *(Note that the returned value is a string)*.
- `index = (parseInt(index) || 1) - 1`: Try to convert `index` to a number, if that worked out and the resulting number is not `0` then subtract `1` from the returned value, otherwise return `1` and then subtract `1` from it thus giving us `0`, the main idea here is that it seems we are trying to get an index to an array so the index can't be less than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`/\d+/` means one or more digits.

> `+` means one or more of the preceding element.

Also [**exec**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

> If the match succeeds, the exec method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured.
>
> If the match fails, the exec method returns null.

Answer (score 1):

In a regular expression `\d` will match a single number. The `+` in the regex will match repeats of the expression before it. So `\d+` will match a full (all repetive) number.

So

```
"55".match(/\d+/) //=>["55"]
"55".match(/\d/) //=>["5"]
"A string with 55".match(/\d+/) //=>["55"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hash = window.location.hash; //store the entered hash value eg, #02
```

Just gets the # part of the URL

```
if (hash) {
```

Checks if the hash is not empty

```
    index = /\d+/.exec(hash)[0];
```

Tries to match the hash against a sequence of digits (that's what \d+ means) and assigns the first such sequence to index

```
    index = (parseInt(index) || 1) - 1;
```

Just converts index to a number and decreases it by 1

If the hash contains no digits, this code throws an exception, so it's not very robust